# no warning on unused lambda with -Wall and -Wextra

Tags: c++, lambda, g++, clang++, static-code-analysis

Normally, if you have a lambda and forget to use it, you'll get a warning (if enabled) like any other unused variable.

```
auto foo = [](){};
```

would generate `warning: unused variable 'foo'` or similar.

However, if the lambda captures have side-effects (like bumping the ref count of a `shared_ptr`), you won't get the warning.

```
auto x = std::make_shared<int>(23);
auto foo = [x](){ bar(*x); };
```

So, short of creating my own `[[nodiscard]]` wrapper for function objects, are there any extra warning flags I'm missing or static analysis tools that'd pick up this mistake?

Mainly a gcc user, although would be building with clang as well off the same code base.

Comment: had to convince myself. Here's the demo: https://godbolt.org/z/d7sMbv

Comment: As far as I'm aware, just declaring `foo` like that will have a side effect of changing the use_count of `x`. So I'm not sure an unused-warning would even be correct.

Comment: @cigien I think I agree, but I think the results are still surprising, as the lambda is unused.  My question is really whether there's _any_ way I can detect this mistake

Comment: See my answer below, I fleshed out the comment. Can you explain exactly what you think the mistake actually is here? That would be important for deciding whether/what kind of warning should be emitted.

Comment: @cigien the mistake is that I forgot to invoke the lambda.  My real-world mistake was a bit more involved, but essentially `foo` should've been immediately invoked.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not convinced that's a mistake. Take `int x = 42;` for example; if you never use `x` then yes, I'd say it's a mistake, and a warning should be emitted. But in your case, declaring `foo` has an effect. What if you *wanted* that effect just from the declaration? The compiler has no way of knowing you actually didn't want that, and that you *meant* to invoke it immediately.

Comment: @cigien if I wanted the effect, and -Wunused warned on un-invoked lambdas, I could use [[maybe_unused]] to suppress the warning.   I'm not disputing the behaviour of -Wunused though.  I am wanting some way to check if a lambda hasn't been invoked, as it was a mistake in my code.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you would have liked the compiler to warn about the bug in your code. But compiler warnings are for code that is almost certainly a bug. That's subjective of course, but one would have to make the argument that code like you've written basically never makes sense. And I don't know if that's the case here.

Comment: Here's an example that might help: Let's say a lambda is only used in an unevaluated context, or maybe you want to do some meta-programming that uses just the type of a lambda. Do you want the compiler to warn about all those lambdas just because they are never *invoked*?

Comment: @cigien no, but I only said invocation for the sake of brevity.  properties of the lambda capture affect whether I get -Wunused or not in my example, and in the meta-programming and unevaluated context cases you would not expect to get the -Wunused error.  I can see now though that any type, not just a lambda, that bumped a ref count of a shared_ptr would count as "use" as far as -Wunused is concerned.  I also asked about static analysis tools also, so will see if I get any pointers towards those.  Cheers

Comment: My guess is that static analyzers would run into similar problems as the warnings case, i.e. it's very hard to know what you *meant*. But it's certainly possible that some static analyzers have some fine-grained settings that will catch this kind of thing (probably with a high false-positive rate though).

Answer (score 2):

There's not really anything to warn about in your program. At least, any warnings that might be produced wouldn't fall in the category of `-Wunused`. That set of warnings is for declarations in a program that have no effect on the behavior of the program, suggesting a programmer mistake. This is generally the case for unused declarations, since declarations by themselves don't usually have any observable side effects.

In your code however, the declaration of `foo` *does* have an observable side effect:

```
auto x = std::make_shared<int>(23);
std::cout << x.use_count();         // prints 1
auto foo = [x](){ bar(*x); };
std::cout << x.use_count()          // prints 2
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a9Pax7).

So I don't think any `-Wunused` warnings would be appropriate for this program.